# Some stats for the Lifehacks Community

Tags: discussion

The site is in Beta since December 2014 and now we have about 8400 users. I have made some analysis of these users which I want to share it. Maybe some of you will find it interesting.

1. **Users age**

[image: Usets age]

The users who have shared their age are mostly between 18 and 40. Most of all users prefer not to share their age.

2. **New users**

[image: new users]

Here are the new users which join the community each month since the start of Lifehacks Beta in December 2014. There are about 400 - 500 new users each month.

3. **Users activity**

Unfortunately a big part of the users are not active.
In these analysis a user is counted as **not active** if he/she has no comments and posts (questions or answers), maybe some of them have only voted.

[image: users activity]

Only 28% of all 8400 users have ever posted a Question, an Answer or a Comment.

- Last activity

On the next chart is shown the number of users which have last posted/commented in each month.

[image: last post]

This is not very representative, but the next picture gives more clear understanding how many inactive users we have in each month.

- inactive users each month

[image: inactive users by month]

These users have a comment or post after joining the community, but after that they stop contributing the site. Here is not included the amount of users who have no comments or posts.

4. **Users visiting the site**

[image: Last seen]

Here is the number of registered users which have last visited the site in each month and after that they have not entered Lifehacks.

On the next picture you can see how many users have not visited the site during each month. We have 7000 registered users which have not visited Lifehacks in February 2016.

[image: not seen]

5. **Active users February 2016**

[image: active users February 2016]

The most active users are the new users. And there is also activity from users registered in December 2014, these are the creators of Lifehacks which are still active and support the community. Some users which registered later still keep their enthusiasm. But this number is really small compared the the number of users which are registering each month.

Comment: But what's the question?

Comment: It is not a question. Just some information

Comment: But I mean there must a point to be made out of this information.

Comment: The point I made for myself is that too many users are inactive, they  don't write questions and answers, just come , maybe find what they were looking for and then, they don't visit the site again. We have more than 9000 visitors a day and only 2 questions per day, which is the only bad number for Lifehacks in Area 51.

Comment: @JustDoIt this is meta, not everything has to be a question.

Comment: +1 Nice stats. I'm really curious to see how the active user percentage stacks up against other SE sites.

Comment: @Wipqozn do you have in mind any particular SE site for comparison?

Comment: @vladiz Engineering, since they'are about the same age as Lifehacks, Mathematica, since they're  a launched site with similar traffic, and Japanese Language, since they have about the same number of active users (a lot older than us though).